# AlertDialog box to send message

Tags: android, dialog, logcat

Im trying to make my AlertDialog box to send message. For that I've used SmsManagers on button of dialog box. The dialog box I've created uses custom layout. What I want is that when I click on "ok" button then a message will be sent to a predefined number which I declare in SmsManager. Instead, when I click on ok button the application crashes

Code for AlertDialog box :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button addnew, dialog;
ListView lvInb;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
int count = 0;
EditText editSMS;
SharedPreferences prefs=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lvInb = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvInb);
    addnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddnew);
    addnew.setOnClickListener(this);
    dialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnproperty);
    dialog.setOnClickListener(this);

    editSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSMS);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    count=prefs.getInt("count", 0);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        myButton.setId(count);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
    }
    lvInb = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvInb);
    lvInb.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    if(fetchInbox()!=null)
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 , fetchInbox());
        lvInb.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lvInb.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> fetchInbox()
{
     ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
     Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
     Cursor cr = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);
     cr.moveToFirst();
        while  (cr.moveToNext())
        {
             sms.add(cr.getString(1)+"\n"+cr.getString(3)+"\n");
        }
        return sms;


    }





@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == dialog)
    {


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog2.setTitle("Message");
        alertDialog2.setMessage("Enter Related Text");
        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog2.setView(input);
        alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                String phoneNo = "111";
                 String sms = editSMS.getText().toString();
                 try {
                         SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS failed, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

            }


        });
    alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reverting Changes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    alertDialog2.show();

    }


    if(v == addnew)
    {

        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
        count++;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", count);
        editor.commit();
    }


}
```

}

Also logcat is showing errors like:

```
Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(2537): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a3bb90)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.helloworld, PID: 2470
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.example.helloworld.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:198)
com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the full Logcat, there should be a 'Caused by: ' part that is rather important.

Comment: Did you added Permission into manifest.xml?

Comment: Is editSMS correctly initiate ? Maybe it's null, please copy your whole Logcat trace

Comment: @M D I've added permission to send message in manifest.xml

Comment: @user3172071 what is line number 198 in  MainActivity.java

Comment: @HAriharan Tamilan Line no 198 is String sms = editSMS.getText().toString();

Comment: @user3172071 can you post that what is `editSMS` . did you initilize that `editSMS`

Comment: in main activity:  EditText editSMS; and in onCreate : editSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSMS);

Answer (score 0):

please remove line `alertDialog2.show();`

and use these lines

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialog2.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```

also do not for to add permission  at manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: the application still crashes if i click on Ok Button

Answer (score 0):

Try to initilize your `EditText` like below in your `MainActivity` inside `OnCreate`

```
editSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idname);
```

for you `editSMS`

Comment: @user3172071 Post your full `MainActivity.java`

Comment: @ Hariharan Tamilan Check my main activity i've post my full MainActivity.java

Comment: Yes still i'm getting error and its of null pointer exception

Comment: @user3172071 is it in the same line.

Comment: there is no line number specified but the log cat showing that error "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 0):

String sms = editSMS.getText().toString();

change this to

String sms = input.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Message length could be the problem. Try using `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method instead of `sendTextMessage()`.
Below is my sample code:

```
    private static void sendMessage(String message){

    String number = m_Text;

    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        //smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
        ArrayList<String> messageParts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);

        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, messageParts, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(sContext, "Message Sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(sContext,ex.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```